# I have an error on this prolog code line 10 word first I cant figure it out what's my mistake plz help me

Tags: prolog, expert-system

```
go:- 
    university(area),
    write('Shall we start?: '),
    write(area),
    nl,
    undo.
    
university(csandse) :- csandse, !.
    
csandse :-
    verify(labs),
    verify(classrooms),
    verify(Teachers Staffroom),
    verify(Department's faculty office).
    
ask(Question):-
    write('which area of department you want to visit?: '),
    write(Question),
    write('? '),
    read(Response),
    nl,
    ( (Response == yes; Response == y)
    
    assert(yes(Question));
    assert(no(Question)), fail).
    
:- dynamic yes/1, no/1.
    
verify(S) :-
    (yes(S)
    true ;
    (no(S)
    
    fail ;
    ask(S))).
```

Comment: Wrap text such as `Teachers` and `Department's` in single quotes - https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=text-representation

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 3):

I've edited the question to add code formatting; we can see the colour changes midway through Department's faculty office:

[image: Screenshot of code]

because the apostrophe is throwing it off. The same colour change happens in [SWISH](https://swish.swi-prolog.org/). As @brebs comments, things starting with a capital are Variables and must be wrapped in single quotes to be atoms. Ones with quotes used as apostrophes need to have the apostrophe escaped with a backslash:

```
verify('Department\'s faculty office')
```